# Materialize Modal not displayed on Angular 7

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, materialize, angular7

I've been trying multiple thing of displaying a modal from materialize. I've been through all the [steps](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) of setting up materialize.

All seems to be good since I am using the icons.

I eventually followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OImBxPnTLZw) but at 2:40 his modal opens, mine doesn't.

The only difference from his project and mine is that I have installed materialize via NPM and that I am using Angular 7. I have no other packages. Is there something with Angular 7 that interferes that doe not open my modal?

Thank you for your help. You may find the code from my Angular template bellow.
I am not getting any error, but the modal does not open.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Modals</h2>

    <a href="#terms" class="btn orange modal-trigger">Terms & conditions</a>

    <div class="modal" id="terms">
        test
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.modal').modal();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You should include your code and the steps to reproduce the issue on your question, instead of linking to a video. Also, are you getting any error?

Comment: @GCSDC, I pasted a link instead of my code (facepalm). Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Angular comes with [Material](https://material.angular.io/). I highly recommend using it for modals; it works right out of the box without loading jquery.

Answer (score 1):

In your Index.html write this code

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
  });

</script>
```

i hope this fix your problem